# laravel application won't save images but stores its file name to data base

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, webforms

So I am using laravel and Intervention Image package.
My form accepts the picture, save its name to DB but picture is never saved.
Why?

Thanks!

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $img=Image::make($request->file('slika')); //slika-name of input field, and Slike my desired folder.
    $img->save('Slike');


    $this->validate($request,[
        'naziv'=>'required|string|max:30',
        'mesto'=>'required|integer|max:4',
    ]);

    $crs=new Crossroad();
    $crs->naziv=$request->naziv; //the name of the crossroad
    $crs->mesto=$request->mesto; //number of turns in it
    $crs->slika=$request->slika; //picture's name(string in DB)

    $crs->save();

    return redirect('/crossroads/index');
}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Edit your question and post the code into the body. Indent it with 4 spaces and it will automatically be formatted. It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please change the title of your Q. It's not informative now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
if ($request->hasFile('slika')) {

$image = $request->file('slika');
$name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$destinationPath = public_path('/path/to/');
$image->move($destinationPath, $name);

}
```

Comment: One more thing is problem now. In my input field i have for example: "image1.jpg", and that is the string that should be stored as file name.
Instead, i get something like this D:\xampp\tmp\php23BD.tmp(this is the name of file)..
What can be the issue there?